# Error: fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":20,"message":"Authentication failure"}]]

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I started my network and registered some Identities through node-sdk like in balance-transfer app. Now I want somehow identities persistence so that if my ca-server container is restarted due to some reasons i can use already registered and enrolled identities.I think What happened here is ca-server did not recognize old identities. Is there is anyway to use older identities? I am using hyperledger fabric 1.4[ca-container logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo6nF.png)